# flexslider images how to add title

Tags: flexslider

I need to add a title to my image so that flexslider will show that as the caption.  However I cannot figure out how to add a title to the image field in drupal 7 .  I tried adding fields to the file type image admin/config/media/file-types/manage/image/display
but it doesnt take what I put in in the form .

Answer (score 1):

If you create your own template, copy the original and add print the title-caption like this with either the alt or title field:

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
  <?php foreach ($items as $img):?>

  <li><?php print render ($img) ; ?>

  <?php if (!empty($img['#item']['alt'])) { ?>
    <p class="title-caption"><?php print $img['#item']['alt']; ?></p>
  <?php } ?>

  </li>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>


<?php 
  $counter = count($items);
  if($counter > 0){ ?>
  <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
    <?php foreach ($items as $img): ?>
      <li><?php print render($img); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
 </div>
<?php  }
```

Then add to your css:

```
.title-caption {
position: absolute;
width: 99%;
padding: 10px;
bottom: 0px;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 28px;
margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone has answered this for me here http://drupal.org/node/1067620#comment-6994238
You have to edit the content type, then edit the image and if you scroll down there is a check box for "Enable Title"